Drizzle relational queries - get the total rows count before applying LIMIT and OFFSET
using drizzle relational queries is it possible to know the total rows count before applying LIMIT and OFFSET? if yes, how?
//this is full query sample without geting the totalCount
  async many(params: FilmQueryParams): Promise<FilmDetailed[]> {
    const filmsDB = (await this._db.query.filmTable.findMany({
      limit: params.pageSize,
      offset: (params.pageNumber - 1) * params.pageSize,
      with: {
        categories: { with: { category: true } },
        actors: { with: { actor: true } },
        language: true,
      },
      where: (film, { eq, and, or, like }) => {
        let conditions = [];

        if (params?.textToSearch !== "") {
          conditions.push(like(film.title, `%${params?.textToSearch}%` || ""));
        }
        return or(...conditions);
      },

      orderBy: (films, { desc }) => [desc(films.releaseYear)],
    })) as FilmDetailedDB[];
    return this.convertToFilmsDetailed(filmsDB);
  }

